# Web3js 1.0 events: closing the contract.events "socket"

Tags: contract-development, events, web3js-v1.x

My code is the following:

```
contract.events.Deposit({}, function (err, event) {
    if (err) {
        console.error;
    } else {
        console.log(event.blockNumber);
    }
})
    .on('data', function (event) {
        console.log(event);
    })
```

What I want to do is to close the event listener after some condition is fulfilled. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The web3.js 1.0 documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#contract-events-return) states that the return value of creating an event is an EventEmitter. To close the event, you have to [remove all of the EventEmitter's listeners](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_removealllisteners_eventname) using the bound event's names:

```
// set up emitter:
let emitter = contract.events.Deposit({}, function (err, event) {
    if (err) {
        console.error;
    } else {
        console.log(event.blockNumber);
    }
})
.on('data', function (event) {
    console.log(event);
})

// ==== //

//Somewhere else in your code where you have access to the emitter:
// Close emitter:
emitter.removeAllListeners('data');
```

Comment: `removeAllListeners` method is not in the documentation.